# Cast warning when working with structures

Tags: c

I'm revisiting C after a long time and am puzzled by a warning generated by the compiler. Here's the relevant code:

```
struct Unit 
{
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];
    short expected;
};

int main()
{
    struct Unit arr[] = 
    {
        {NULL, NULL, 0},
        {NULL, "string", -1},
        {"string", NULL, 1},
        {"string", "string", 0},
        {"string1", "string2", -1},
        {"string2", "string1", 1},
        {"str", "string", -1},
        {"string", "str", 1}
    };

    printf("%d\n", arr[0].expected);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled, I get:

```
my_strcmp.c: In function ‘main’:
my_strcmp.c:64:9: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
         {NULL, NULL, 0},
         ^
my_strcmp.c:64:9: warning: (near initialization for ‘arr[0].str1[0]’) [enabled by default]
my_strcmp.c:64:9: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
my_strcmp.c:64:9: warning: (near initialization for ‘arr[0].str1[1]’) [enabled by default]
my_strcmp.c:65:9: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
         {NULL, "string", -1},
         ^
my_strcmp.c:65:9: warning: (near initialization for ‘arr[1].str1[0]’) [enabled by default]
my_strcmp.c:65:9: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
my_strcmp.c:65:9: warning: (near initialization for ‘arr[1].str1[1]’) [enabled by default]
my_strcmp.c:66:9: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
         {"string", NULL, 1},
         ^
my_strcmp.c:66:9: warning: (near initialization for ‘arr[2].str2[0]’) [enabled by default]
```

I don't get it; where am I making integer from pointer? Please help.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Man, just assume they are there! I didn't post the whole code.

Comment: Initializing an array with NULL does not make any sense. Change the NULL to ""

Comment: Why are you trying to initialize a `char[100]` array with a `NULL`? What is it supposed to mean? `NULL` is supposed to be used with pointers, not with arrays.

Comment: @AnT I was just thinking that since arrays are implicitly pointers, this will cause `NULL` to get assigned to the internal pointer of `str1`, `str2`, etc. :P

Comment: _arrays are implicitly pointers_ - This is incorrect

Comment: @dotslash: Arrays are not "implicitly pointers". There's no such thing as "internal pointer" for an array.

Comment: You obviously know how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But in the future use the output (errors or other) from the MCVE instead, so it's easier to connect the line numbers in the error messages to the lines in the code you show. Even then you should mark out the erroneous lines in the code with e.g. comments.

Comment: @AnT As I said I'm revisiting this after years so have forgotten most of it. I remember reading that `arr[5]` get converted to something like `*(arr + 5)` by the compiler. So I thought ...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Good point! I didn't think about the line numbers. :-)

Comment: @dotslash: That's true. But the "array pointer" you are talking about is itself a result of temporary conversion. It exists only conceptually. It is created as a temporary value "on the fly" to participate in `*(arr + 5)` and disappears immediately afterwards. It does not exist physically in memory. You cannot assign anything to it.

Comment: @AnT Hmm, now I think I remember reading something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that line 64, 65 and 66 are the ones where you initialize the structure using `NULL`. That will not work because `NULL` is a pointer, and you can't initialize an array with a pointer.

The only solution I can see is to either turn the string arrays in the structure to pointers, or to initialize the "unused" strings to the empty string `""`.

Comment: All right, thanks! I thought the `NULL` would somehow automatically get assigned to the internal pointer representation of an array. Too much Python, I guess. ;-)

Comment: @dotslash Arrays naturally *decays* to pointers, but they are not pointers themselves.

Comment: "Decays"? Do you mean "converted" or is there some actual analogue of, say, matter decaying?

Comment: The C standards do not use the word "decay" at all.   In this context the word  "decay" informally describes an implicit conversion of an array to a pointer to its first element  (e.g. when passing an array to a function that accepts a pointer as an argument).    However, a pointer cannot be used to initialise an array (e.g. `char *some_array[10] = some_pointer_to_char`) or assigned to an array (e.g. `some_array = some_pointer_to_char`).